Changing internal storage of DateTime property?
I'm wanting to store the clock in and clockout properties in dd-mm-yyyy hh-mm but dont want anything else stored. Is this possible to do?
public class TimeCard
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime ClockIn { get; set; }

        public DateTime ClockOut { get; set; }

        public bool IsIn { get; set; }

        public string Comment { get; set; }

I had thought about using a string format and extracting that information but I'm not really sure how I would go about that either? I had thought about doing it this way in the methods used elsewhere,  using these properties converting to strings within them but wanted a way to store it within the class itself is possible (My idea below). Sorry I'm very new to coding and any help would be appreciated!
 ClockIn = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd:M:yyyy:H:m"),

You can't change how DateTime stores things internally, no. What you can do is format ClockIn and ClockOut whenever you need a string representation of them. You could even add FormattedClockIn and FormattedClockOut properties if you wish, e.g.
public class TimeCard
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime ClockIn { get; set; }
    public DateTime ClockOut { get; set; }
    public bool IsIn { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    // TODO: Consider specifying an appropriate culture in the ToString call.
    public string FormattedClockIn => ClockIn.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    public string FormattedClockOut => ClockOut.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
}

That way it's easy for anyone wanting consistent formatting to achieve it, without making it difficult to use the "real" data. It's almost certainly going to be more appropriate than changing the type of ClockIn and ClockOut directly.
